# Stream video from phone camera using ionic framework

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, live-streaming

I am trying to build a mobile phone app using Ionic Framework to live stream video captured through phone camera. This is very similar to https://www.periscope.tv/

I will capture this stream on my server, transcode and then distribute it again. I looked into the camera plugin for cordova https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera. I am not sure if it is possible to live stream from camera using ionic framework.
If not, what are my other options except for going native.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look for this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2LOpmCpK-g

This is a quick demo of setting up and running the RTCOMM Mobile Sample app. This sample uses the Ionic framework and angular-rtcomm library to build a Hybrid Mobile application.

I followed this tutorial and works! I recomend you to try first running from an iPhone (iOS 9.3 in my case) and make a call to a browser (Firefox 45.0.2), works perfectly. I also tried with Android, but has some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use ionic framework to embed video streaming for mobile app and the reference for the link is [Nic raboy video](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/01/embed-video-ios-android-ionicframework-app/) in Ionic and the plugin for the project is [camera](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/), you can edit this plugin documents based upon your requirements in delaying the app to show and inject $http service in your controller to send the data to server

Comment: links are broken